# How should I indicate to users that Escape can close a modal?

Tags: modal-windows

The modal windows on our site have a Close button (X) in the upper right corner, and for years that's been the only way to close them.  I just added the ability to close modals by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.  I want to let our longterm users (and our new users, too) know that this functionality is available.  Is there a good / standard way to show that hint?  Maybe as a title on the Close button?  Are there any examples of where this is done well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

**Try adding a tooltip, with info about the shortcut key,** to the Close button (x).

Users will have to discover this -- but it's a one-time learn.

Comment: I think I am going to give this a try.

Comment: A tooltip is probably the most useless thing possible, you'd have to have the mouse above the button, just a short click away, why bother with the esc then. The esc key is useful mostly to keyboard and assistive technology users, who don't rely on a mouse, so it would have to be somehow displayed right away.

Answer (score 0):

I would add in the functionality and let users find it organically. You could add a tooltip, since it's a one-time learn, but unless you have many modals that a user has to navigate through on a regular basis, learning to close with esc instead of a click isn't a big win and almost results in a wash.

Comment: we do have a ton of modals used on a regular basis.